# How can I stop my labels going on top of one another?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="emptyGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label x:Name="emptyLabel1" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" />
    <Label x:Name="emptyLabel2" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" />
    <Label x:Name="emptyLabel3" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" />
 </Grid>
```

All my 2-5 line labels appear on top of each other but what I would like is for them to evenly fill out the space given to them:

Comment: Your XAML looks incoplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StackLayout which will lay them down next to each other horizontally or vertically and set VerticalOptions so that they fill the space they're given:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="emptyLabel1" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Label x:Name="emptyLabel2" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Label x:Name="emptyLabel3" FontSize="18" XAlign="Center" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
 </Grid>
```